# Check distinct value ignoring other columns data

Tags: php, sql, distinct

If I have a table with data like this :

```
   Col1 |  Col2 | Col3

   111  |  a     | 

   222  |  b     |  1

   111  |        |
```

And I wish to select Distinct Col1 only from my temporary table then insert into another table.But with the table above , the second "111" will be selected as well since it has different Col2 data.

Or if I select Distinct Col1 only , the other columns data will be ignored...

So is there any way to solve this problem? I wish to choose only the first inserted row of same Col1 data.

I'm using this query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT DELAYED INTO Tableb (Col1,Col2,Col3) SELECT DISTINCT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM TempTable");
```

Thanks for any reply.

PS: I'm not sure how to specified the title according to my question...perhaps someone can help me.

Comment: how do you determine that which '111' is newest?

Comment: @Vikram Thanks for your reply.Should be using the oldest ID ,the first inserted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to determine last ID per distinct value of col1, and then you select rows containing this id:

```
INSERT DELAYED INTO Tableb (Col1,Col2,Col3) 
SELECT TempTable.Col1, TempTable.Col2, TempTable.Col3
from TempTable
inner join
(
   select Col1, max(ID) ID
     from TempTable
    group by Col1
) c
ON TempTable.ID = c.ID
```

Inner query returns ID's to be inserted, so one simply joins them to original table to filter the table.

Substitute max(id) with min(id) if you want first inserted TempTable record.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this (this is probably what you want):

```
INSERT INTO Tableb
(
    Col1,Col2,Col3
)
SELECT
    t.Col1,
    MAX(t.Col2) AS Col2,
    MAX(t.Col3) AS Col3
FROM
    TempTable as t
GROUP BY
    t.Col1
```

Or if you want the MIN value. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO Tableb
(
    Col1,Col2,Col3
)
SELECT
    t.Col1,
    MIN(t.Col2) AS Col2,
    MIN(t.Col3) AS Col3
FROM
    TempTable as t
GROUP BY
    t.Col1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I'm now trying it.Can I know what is the "t" for? such as t.Col1,t.Col2..it shows me "unknown column t.xxx".

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your updated. I tried it but it seems I'm facing a little problem , not sure what is the problem yet but will look into it again , thanks you very much for your help,your answer give me a very good concept.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. If you are fine with the answer you might consider accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT DELAYED INTO Tableb (Col1,Col2,Col3) SELECT Col1, MAX(t.Col2) AS Col2, MAX(t.Col3) AS Col3 FROM TempTable GROUP BY Col1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT DELAYED INTO Tableb (Col1,Col2,Col3) SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM TempTable GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY [your way of sorting here]
```

Does that do it?